GCP Pub/Sub Publish - Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage
I am using the C# quickstart code from this docs page for publishing messages to a Pub/Sub topic: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library#publish_messages
I have made some changes to facilitate the authentication method required by my use case. The key is to a service account with the roles/pubsub.admin role (Though I should mention that running this code after removing this role from from the service account produces the same error).
My code is as follows:
string[] testStrings = [
    "Hello world!"
];

var gcpJsonCredsDecoded = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCP_PUBSUB_KEY");
var gcpCreds = GoogleCredential.FromJson(gcpJsonCredsDecoded);

TopicName topicName = TopicName.FromProjectTopic(
    projectId: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCP_PROJECT_ID"),
    topicId: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCP_PUBSUB_TOPIC")
);

var publisherClient = new PublisherClientBuilder {
    TopicName = topicName,
    Credential = gcpCreds,
}.Build();

int publishedMessageCount = 0;
var publishTasks = testStrings.Select(async text =>
{
    try
    {
        string message = await _publisherClient.PublishAsync(text);
        Console.WriteLine($"Published message {message}");
        Interlocked.Increment(ref publishedMessageCount);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred when publishing message {text}: {exception.Message}");
    }
});

await Task.WhenAll(publishTasks);

Console.WriteLine($"Published message count: {publishedMessageCount}");

This produces the following error:
An error occurred when publishing message Hello world!: One or more errors occurred. (Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage. (ep.threatpulse.net:80) InvalidOperationException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage. (ep.threatpulse.net:80)"))

Could anyone provide a solution or some advice to diagnose?
EDIT: I am using .NET 8.0 and and the Nuget package Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 3.16.0.

Please include .NET version and the NuGet imports|versions so that others can repro

It isn't the problem but, it's better to use Application Default Credentials and not manually juggle JSON keys and environment variables in your code.

@DazWilkin See my edit for .NET and Nuget package version. Re: Default credentials, these are not suitable for my use case.

It's getting late here but I'll try this tomorrow. I don't understand your comment about ADC. The client libraries support ADC to simplify the code and enhance portability. Manually specifying the Service Account key in your code is functionally equivalent.

@WillSutton are you running the code from any VM or K8s pod. If yes, then it may be restricted to route the traffic outside your VPC. Is it possible to use some proxy server or something?

@SasirekhaMSVL Thanks for the suggestion. I ran the code again earlier and it seems to be working now for no good reason. I think it may have been something to do with my VPN/network, but I did make changes to other sections of the code. I will investigate further tomorrow and write a full answer if I have any useful findings.

I have confirmed that my VPN was the cause of my issue, though I have not identified any particular network settings that were affecting this code.
